# Is there a way in flask to get each object in the request.json and save each attribute on the model?

Tags: python, flask, refactoring, flask-sqlalchemy, parameters

I have the following verbose code which sets each variable from `request.json['example']` and then Saves the model `Inventory`. Is there a way to do this with much less code? for Example in ruby I can simply pass the params to `Inventory(inventory_params)`.

```
@api.route('/new/<id>', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def new_item(id):
    date_opened = None
    date_expired = None
    received_date = None
    order_date = None
    if len(request.json['opened']) >= 1:
        date_opened = datetime.strptime(request.json['opened'], '%m/%d/%Y')
        print(date_opened)
    if len(request.json['expiration_date']) >= 1:
        date_expired = datetime.strptime(request.json['expiration_date'], '%m/%d/%Y')
    if len(request.json['received_date']) >= 1:
        received_date = datetime.strptime(request.json['received_date'], '%m/%d/%Y')
    if len(request.json['order_date']) >= 1:
        order_date = datetime.strptime(request.json['order_date'], '%m/%d/%Y')
    amount=request.json['amount']
    units=request.json['units']
    location=request.json['location']
    opened=request.json['opened']
    lot=request.json['lot']
    batch=request.json['batch']
    notes=request.json['notes']
    price=request.json['price']
    country_code=request.json['country_code']
    secondary_location=request.json['secondary_location']
    vendor_code=request.json['vendor']
    uid = request.json['uid']
    item = Inventory(vendor_code=vendor_code, country_code=country_code, price=price, secondary_location=secondary_location, lot=lot, original_amount=amount, amount=amount, original_units=units, units=units, location=location, plant_material_id=id, uid=uid, batch=batch, notes=notes, date_opened=date_opened, date_expired=date_expired, received_date=received_date, order_date=order_date )
    db.session.add(item)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({'results': True})
```

Comment: You should be able to use [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) (assuming your `request.json` doesn't include any keys that aren't valid keyword arguments for the constructor of `Inventory`). Something along the lines of  `Inventory(**request.json)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) for this.

The basic principle is that if you have a function or a method that accepts keyword arguments, like

```
def foo(bar=42, qux=None):
    pass
```

you can instead of calling it like `foo(bar=1, qux=23)` take those arguments from a dictionary and pass them to the function by **unpacking** them (that's what the `**` syntax does):

```
kwargs = {'bar': 1, 'qux': 23}

foo(**kwargs)
```

---

Because in your case there's not a strict 1:1 relationship between your keys/values in `requests.json` and the required arguments for the constructor of your `Inventory`, you will need to do some pre-processing of those values, and therefore

- remove the raw values from the arguments dict after you processed them
- add the processed values to the arguments dict with the proper key

After you built your argument dictionary, `Inventory(**params)` will pass *all* those arguments to `Inventory.__init__()`, so you need to make sure you match the method's signature.

Here's a self-contained example (no Flask or SQLAlchemy, but it really makes no difference):

```
from datetime import datetime


params = {
    'opened': '05/07/2015',
    'vendor_code': 'VC',
    'country_code': 'US',
}


class Inventory(object):
    def __init__(self, vendor_code=None, country_code=None, date_opened=None):
        self.vendor_code = vendor_code
        self.country_code = country_code
        self.date_opened = date_opened

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.__dict__)


def create_inventory(params):
    # Deal with a raw value that needs to be processed
    date_opened = None
    if len(params['opened']) >= 1:
        date_opened = datetime.strptime(params['opened'], '%m/%d/%Y')

    # Remove the raw value from the params dict
    params.pop('opened')

    # Add the processed value to the `params` dict with the proper key
    params['date_opened'] = date_opened

    # All the other parameters get passed through unmodified
    inv = Inventory(**params)
    return inv

print create_inventory(params)
```

Comment: I always add `*args, **kwargs` to the list of arguments of the target function since this way if you are using a dictionary that has more keys than the necessary you don't have to filter out

Comment: @rll good point - but I'd probably be hesitant to always do this, since this could mask subtle errors. Also, with SQLAlchemy models `__init__()` is often inherited, not sure how that would work there.